# Excluding a saved value in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How do I exclude a saved part of a regular expression in the search box, something like this but it doesn't work:

`(.)e[^\1]`

where it won't match words like: aea, beb... and so on.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please add example it should match, also example which shouldn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

Find: `(.)e(?!\1)`

`(?!\1)` makes sure we haven't the same character before and after the `e`.

If you want to match the last character, use:

Find: `(.)e(?!\1).`